# Visual recognition of local file with Watson

Tags: python, watson, visual-recognition

I believe this is a simple question. When using the Watson API via Python, I have no issues running it to detect an image URL. However, I do have trouble doing it for local picture files.

My code:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 as vr
instance = vr('2016-05-20', api_key='Your-Api-key')
img2 = instance.classify(images_file='a.jpg')
print(img2)
```

The error output is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-173-79c8a4eee873> in <module>()
----> 1 img2 = instance.classify(images_file='a.jpg') C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\visual_recognition_v3.py in classify(self, images_file, images_url, classifier_ids, owners, threshold)
    154                   'owners': owners, 'threshold': threshold}
    155         return self._image_call('/v3/classify', images_file, images_url,
--> 156                                 params)
    157 
    158     def detect_faces(self, images_file=None, images_url=None): C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watson_developer_cloud\visual_recognition_v3.py in _image_call(self, url, images_file, images_url, params)

    124                                 accept_json=True)
    125         else:
--> 126             filename = images_file.name
    127             mime_type = mimetypes.guess_type(
    128                 filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream' 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I am using rodeo IDE. I have tried changing the working directory to the image folder or inputting `C:/...` etc., but neither of these work.

I believe it is the way I pass the argument, can someone guide me?

Essentially, what does

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to pass it a file not the name of the file. so try:

```
img2 = instance.classify(images_file=open('a.jpg', 'rb'))
```

notice that now you're passing a file object with `open('a.jpg', 'rb')` rather than a str object `'a.jpg'`
To answer the question about the error, python `str` objects don't have `name` attributes, which is exactly what the error is saying.

refer to the example at the watson python sdk github: [visual recognition example](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/visual_recognition_v3.py)

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply. I am not very proficient at python as of now. However i am getting this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 240: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I edited to my answer to reflect the fact that your may  need to read the file as binary. Notice the 'rb'  (read binary) option added to the open function.

Comment: thank you so much, I start python with R background. Therefore, this seems ailen to me. As such, for any argument that requires a file to be pass, i have to do the open option? And from where do you realized that it must be 'rb'? I believe guiding me through the thought process will be good for me to learn :)

Comment: if a file is required as an argument then yes you need to open the file location with open(file_name). To answer you second question here is the python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so:

```
file = open('img_to_classify.jpg', 'rb')
img2 = instance.classify(images_file=file)
print(img2)
```